# Finding CDF of a transformation of a random variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let $Y=F_X^{-1}(U)$ a random variable:

$U$ it is a random variable with a probability density function (pdf) $$f_U (u) = 1$$ for  $0 \leq u < 1$;

$X$ it is a random variable and $F^{-1}_X$ is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function  (cdf) of $X$.

Prove that the CDF of $Y$ is the same of X

---

I am really lost with this problem and I don't know how to start it so I can't show my work yet , so please can you give some hint of what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$P(F^{-1}_X(U) \leq y) = P(U \leq F_X(y))$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! So $F_Y(y)=P(F^{-1}_X(U)\leq y)=P(U\leq F_x(y))=F_U(F_X(y))=F_x(y)$

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.